# How can I check if a WFS Stored Query has been created and if it has been created correctly?

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have created a `Stored Query`.

```
function CreateStoredQuery() {
            var CreateStoredQueryRequest = $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://172.16.206.129:8080/geoserver/KRE_ALKIS/wfs?',
                data: '<wfs:CreateStoredQuery service="WFS" version="2.0.0"'
                    + ' xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"'
                    + ' xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"'
                    + ' xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0"'
                    + ' xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"'
                    + ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'
                    + '<wfs:StoredQueryDefinition id="urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFlur2">'
                    + '<wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xsd:string"/>'
                    + '<wfs:Parameter name="fln" type="xsd:integer"/>'
                    + '<wfs:Parameter name="fsn_zae" type="xsd:integer"/>'
                    + '<wfs:Parameter name="fsn_nen" type="xsd:integer"/>'
                    + '<wfs:QueryExpressionText returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" isPrivate="false">'
                    + '<wfs:Query typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">'
                    + '<fes:Filter>'
                    + '<fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>'
                    + '<fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference>'
                    + '<fes:Literal>${gemarkungsname}</fes:Literal>'
                    + '</fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>'            
                    + '</fes:Filter>'
                    + '</wfs:Query>'
                    + '</wfs:QueryExpressionText>'
                    + '</wfs:StoredQueryDefinition>'
                    + '</wfs:CreateStoredQuery>',
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "text",
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + " - CreateStoredQuery");
                    console.log(thrownError + " - CreateStoredQuery");
                }
            });
```

This was shown to me on the console after creating.

```
    10 Dez 01:13:19 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo
10 Dez 01:13:19 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: createStoredQuery
service = WFS
version = 2.0.0
baseUrl = http://172.16.206.129:8080/geoserver/
storedQueryDefinition[0]:
parameter[0]:
name = gemarkungsname
type = {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}stringparameter[0]:
name = fln
type = {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integerparameter[0]:
name = fsn_zae
type = {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integerparameter[0]:
name = fsn_nen
type = {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer
queryExpressionText[0]:
isPrivate = false
language = urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression
returnFeatureTypes[0] = {KRE_ALIKS}sg_flurstueck_f
value = <wfs:Query typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:KRE_ALKIS="KRE_ALIKS">
    <fes:Filter>
        <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference>
            <fes:Literal>${gemarkungsname}</fes:Literal>
        </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </fes:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
id = urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFlur2
```

After that I wanted to use this `Stored Query`. I have entered this URL in the browser.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/KRE_ALKIS/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFlur2
```

Then I was shown this error.

```
    10 Dez 01:18:00 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo
10 Dez 01:18:00 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error accessign stoed query: urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFlur2
at org.geoserver.wfs.StoredQueryProvider.getStoredQuery(StoredQueryProvider.java:142)
at org.geoserver.wfs.kvp.GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.buildStoredQueries(GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.java:234)
at org.geoserver.wfs.kvp.BaseFeatureKvpRequestReader.read(BaseFeatureKvpRequestReader.java:169)
at org.geoserver.wfs.kvp.GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.read(GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.java:61)
at org.geoserver.wfs.kvp.v2_0.GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.read(GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.java:31)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1548)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:691)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:254)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 892; The element type "null:ValueReference" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</null:ValueReference>".
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:235)
at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:167)
at org.geoserver.wfs.StoredQueryProvider.parseStoredQuery(StoredQueryProvider.java:194)
at org.geoserver.wfs.StoredQueryProvider.parseStoredQuery(StoredQueryProvider.java:186)
at org.geoserver.wfs.StoredQueryProvider.getStoredQuery(StoredQueryProvider.java:140)
... 102 more
```

When I want to list Stored Queries on the server, the one I created does not appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:DescribeStoredQueriesResponse xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://172.16.206.129:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:StoredQueryDescription id="urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById">
        <wfs:Title xml:lang="en">Get feature by identifier</wfs:Title>
        <wfs:Parameter name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
        <wfs:QueryExpressionText isPrivate="true" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFSQueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes=""/>
    </wfs:StoredQueryDescription>
</wfs:DescribeStoredQueriesResponse>
```

I wonder now if the StoredQuery was created or not. I did not see any errors when I created it, and when called in the browser, I would expect an error message telling me that the querie is not there.

How can I check if a WFS Stored Query has been created and if it has been created correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I found out for myself. I can look in the directory `GEOSERER\data_dir\wfs\query\` on the geoserver. Here the `Stored Queries` are stored as an XML file. I could see and delete the faulty one, which the request `DescribeStoredQueries` did not show me.